# SWIFT: If statement in "didBeginContact" function runs too many times

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, sprite-kit

My problem is that the if statement which has scoreUpOne() in it gets run too many times, even if the projectile only hits the evilFlappy once.
Here is my code:

```
func scoreUpOne() {
    if scoreUp == true{
        scoreLabel = scoreLabel++
        myScene.scoreLabel.text = "\(scoreLabel)"
        scoreUp = false
    }
}


func evilFlappyRespawnTimer(timer : NSTimer){
    evilFlappy.position = CGPointMake(940, 320)
    evilFlappy.hidden = false
}


func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "projectile" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "bottomBolt"){
        projectile.hidden = true
    }else if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "projectile" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "topBolt"){
        projectile.hidden = true
    }else if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "topBolt" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "projectile"){
        projectile.hidden = true
    }else if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "bottomBolt" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "projectile"){
        projectile.hidden = true


    }

    if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "projectile" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "evilFlappy") {
        projectile.hidden = true
        evilFlappy.hidden = true


        scoreUp = true
        scoreUpOne()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "evilFlappyRespawnTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }
    else if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "evilFlappy" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "projectile"){

        evilFlappy.hidden = true
        projectile.hidden = true
        scoreUp = true
        scoreUpOne()
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "evilFlappyRespawnTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


    }
    if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "flappy" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "sprite") {
        gameOver()
    }
    else if  (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "sprite" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "flappy") {
        gameOver()
    }
```

The problem is that these if statements run too many times, resulting in the score going up more than one point:

```
if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "projectile" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "evilFlappy") {
    projectile.hidden = true
    evilFlappy.hidden = true


    scoreUp = true
    scoreUpOne()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "evilFlappyRespawnTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
else if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "evilFlappy" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "projectile"){

    evilFlappy.hidden = true
    projectile.hidden = true
    scoreUp = true
    scoreUpOne()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "evilFlappyRespawnTimer:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


}
```

How could I make the score only go up one point for every time that the projectile hits the evilFlappy?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you even using scoreUp? There's no reason for that conditional.

If the score is incremented, update the UI. You can set up Key-Value Observation (KVO) on the score variable to see when it's updated and update the UI accordingly. OR, you could post a notification when the score is updated, and your view can listen for that and update.

Comment: yes i know i don't have to use it, but how does that help me circumvent the problem? can you advise on how i can make a variable which when false will not allow the score if statement to run?

Comment: You don't really need to call the score update function if the score isn't actually updated..

I'd do something like this in your controller:

    `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateScoreUI:", name: "scoreUpdated", object: nil)`

Then you'd have an update function that gets called when the score gets updated.
    `func updateScoreUI(notification: NSNotification) {
    // do your score updating
}`

Comment: Your `updateScoreUI:` function will get called when that "scoreUpdated" notification gets posted. Whenever you update the score, you can post a notification like `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("scoreUpdated", object: nil)`